# Show that the given function is continuous at $(0,0)$ using $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Consider

$$f(x,y) =\begin{cases} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}
} & (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\ 
0 & (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$$

Show that $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

**My method**

We have,

$|f(x,y)-0| = |x||\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}| < \delta\cdot1$.

Consider, $\delta<\varepsilon$. ($\delta>0$)

Then for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta<\varepsilon$ such that $|f(x,y)-0|<\varepsilon$ for all $(x,y)$ that satisfies the inequation $x^2 +y^2 < \delta^2$. Hence, $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: For me seems fine.

Comment: It is not well written though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choice of $\delta$ works. Indeed, choosing $\delta = \varepsilon$ works as well; don't forget, if you were to choose this, then $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \delta$ if and only if $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \varepsilon$.

What's not so clear from your proof is why this choice works. You need to work on your mathematical exposition. The last we see any specifics about $f(x, y)$ is the first line. After this, the choice of $\delta$ is merely asserted. What is it about this function $f(x, y)$ that makes this choice of $\delta$ appropriate?

Here's an argument that I think your proof is missing. Note that
$$x^2 + y^2 \ge y^2$$
as $x^2 \ge 0$. Taking the square root of both sides,
$$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \ge |y|,$$
hence
$$\left|\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right| \le 1 \implies |x| \left|\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right| \le |x| \le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2},$$
by a similar argument as above, involving $x$ instead of $y$. Thus, if we assume $0 < \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \varepsilon$, then
$$|x| \left|\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right| < \varepsilon,$$
which implies $|f(x, y) - 0| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: I've added an answer below. Can you check whether that looks fine or not?

Comment: It's better... still seems a little terse though. But at least now it points towards why the choice of $\delta$ works.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon >0$.

Choose $\delta<\varepsilon$.

If $x^2 + y^2 < \delta \implies |x|<\delta$. Then,

$|f(x,y)-0| = |x||\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}| < \delta\cdot1 < \varepsilon$.

Hence, by $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity, $f(x,y)$ is continous at $(0,0)$.